# confirmation time limit

Tags: bitcoin-core

Reading [How does mining works](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq#how-does-bitcoin-mining-work) and towards the end of the explanation,

> As more people start to mine, the difficulty of finding valid blocks is automatically increased by the network to ensure that the average time to find a block remains equal to 10 minutes.

But in [Why do I have to wait for confirmation?](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq#why-do-i-have-to-wait-10-minutes)

> Each confirmation takes between a few seconds and 90 minutes, with 10 minutes being the average.

Since "finding a block" is "confirmation" of a transaction, the above quotes seam like a contradiction.

The other question is why the difficulty increases when more mining power is available? one would thing the opposite should be true. I must be missing something. Any  explanation for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty of the network adjusts in proportion to the hash rate, so that **on average** a block is found every 10 minutes. Of course, it's still a random process, so sometimes blocks are much shorter and sometimes they're much further apart.

As a result, if more hash power gets added to the network, the difficulty has to go up to compensate. Otherwise doubling the hashrate would result in one block per 5 minutes instead of per 10 minutes.

I don't understand where you think there is a contradiction, but feel free to clarify.